# Selecting sentences from a data frame text column if only the sentences contain any of the keywords from a search list

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, nltk

I have a dataframe where in one column, I have a full text with multiple very long sentences. I used `NLTK` to tokenize the text but now I need to make sure I only extract the sentences that contain any of the words from a given long list of full words. I wrote the following code but the problem with it is that, it is not checking the words in the text as a whole but for example to spot a given word in the search list such as 'tic', it is selecting a sentence that contains the word 'statistic'..

```
symptoms = [long list of words ~ about 100]
new_df = df[df['Sentence'].str.contains('|'.join(symptoms))]
```

Right above this code, I use the below code to tokenize my text.

```
sentences = []
for row in df_no_title.itertuples():
    for sentence in sent_tokenize(row[2]):
        sentences.append((row[1], sentence))    
df = pd.DataFrame(sentences, columns=['Paper_Id', 'Sentence'])
```

Is there a way to check the sentences word by word to find the ones that match with any of the words from my list and only extract those sentences in Python?

Please let me know if I should provide any additional information.

Comment: Would you mind editing your post and apply correct formatting for the code? Python is indentation sensitive and code should not be 'formatted' as block quotes. See the [help page on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for the proper syntax – you'll find it's not too hard.

Comment: @usr2564301 of course, I just fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are using is *almost* good. What you would need is to search for individual words which you can achieve by using `\b` special regex character which matches word boundaries (in regex sense).

Therefore, what would work is:

```
symptoms = [long list of words ~ about 100]
new_df = df[df['Sentence'].str.contains('\b' + '\b|\b'.join(symptoms) + '\b')]
```

You can check how the regular expression used is able to catch the symptoms [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cbheadache%5Cb%7C%5Cbchest%20pain%5Cb%7C%5Cbrunny%20nose%5Cb%7C%5Cbpain%20in%20the%20stomach%5Cb%7C%5Cbhypercapnia%5Cb&test_string=fifty-two%20patients%20had%20a%20severe%20runny%20nose%20with%20a%20p%20aco2%20%E2%89%A5%2060%20mmhg%20and%2028%20a%20severe%20acidosis%20with%20a%20ph%20%3C%207.2.%20all%20subjects%20were%20sedated%20and%20invasive%20mechanically%20ventilated%20in%20a%20pressure%20controlled%20mode%20with%20a%20shorter%20duration%20before%20pecla%20in%20the%20survivor%20group.&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) based on the example below.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I really appreciate it however, I do not think this is the solution as it doesn't find anything matching on the sentences from the symptoms if I use \b added thus, not outputting anything.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a sentence and a short list of `symptoms`?

Comment: Yes, of course:

symptoms = [‘headache’,  ‘chest pain’, ‘runny nose’, ‘pain in the stomach’, ‘hypercapnia’]

sentence = ['fifty-two patients had a severe hypercapnia with a p aco2 ≥ 60 mmhg and 28 a severe acidosis with a ph < 7.2. all subjects were sedated and invasive mechanically ventilated in a pressure controlled mode with a shorter duration before pecla in the survivor group.’]

Comment: @ElifKaya: I am not sure why the solution I am proposing does not work for you. Please see how the regex constructed from symptoms work from the link provided in the answer.